# Paypal Refund Sale REST API Returning: Remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using Paypal .NET SDK to try perform payments and refunds. I have got the payment functionality working however, I am unable to perform refunds. I have been looking through Paypal's documentation and code examples, such as:

- http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-NET-SDK/Samples/SaleRefund.aspx.html
- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#sale_refund

I have based my refund process on from one of Paypal's code examples (first link above) and modified very slightly within my own class library:

```
public class RefundTransaction
{
    private readonly string _paypalUniqueTransactionId;
    private readonly CurrencyEnum _currency;
    private readonly decimal _orderTotal;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a refund with basic key fields.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="paypalUniqueTransactionId"></param>
    /// <param name="currency"></param>
    /// <param name="orderTotal"></param>
    public RefundTransaction(string paypalUniqueTransactionId, CurrencyEnum currency, decimal orderTotal)
    {
        _paypalUniqueTransactionId = paypalUniqueTransactionId;
        _currency = currency;
        _orderTotal = orderTotal;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Processes and completes a refund on a sale transaction.
    /// </summary>
    public void RefundWholeSale()
    {
        #region Set the refund details

        Refund processRefund = new Refund
        {
            amount = new Amount()
            {
                currency = _currency.ToString(),
                total = _orderTotal.ToString("N")
            }
        };

        #endregion

        #region Action the refund

        Sale refundSale = new Sale()
        {
            id = _paypalUniqueTransactionId
        };

        Refund refundResponse = refundSale.Refund(Configuration.GetAPIContext(), processRefund);

        #endregion

    }
}
```

The response I am getting back is 404 error. As I understand it, this API call utilises the `/v1/payments/sale/{sale-id}/refund` endpoint. The Sale ID value I am using is what I store after the user has made a payment: PAY-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.

Am I using the correct "sales ID"? Does the Paypal account need special permissions to allow for refunds via the REST API?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it working. What I thought was the Sale ID, was in fact incorrect. The Sale ID is hidden within the Paypal .NET SDK in the `related_resources` section.

When creating a payment in code I am now storing the Sale ID, which you can retrieve as follows:

```
// Create a payment using a valid APIContext.
Payment createdPayment = payment.Create(Configuration.GetAPIContext());

string id = createdPayment.id; // This is no the Sale ID you're looking for...
string saleId = createdPayment.transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale.id;
```

I hope this helps others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

404 error will occur when the requested resource was not found on the server. I think you missed full API url, try to post below information along with header value.

- URL: `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/&lt;Transaction-Id&gt;/refund`
- Content-Type: `application/json`
- Authorization: `Bearer <Access-Token>`
- Data :

  ```
  {
    "amount":
    {
    "total": "2.34",
    "currency": "USD"
    }
  }
  ```